# MigraDoc Hyperlink with "/select" option

Tags: migradoc

I would like to create a link which opens a folder and selects the specified file in it on Windows. It should work like explorer.exe with the /select switch. I use MigraDoc AddHyperlink(filePath, HyperlinkType.File).

Comment: Which PDF viewer? Can you provide a PDF that does what you want? My gut feeling tells me this cannot be done, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MigraDoc creates documents (PDF, RTF, HTML, potentially others) and a hyperlink can only do what the created document supports.

You can add links to other documents giving specific filenames. AFAIK you cannot add links to file-browser dialogues or to EXE files.

With PDF there may be more options, provided you add JavaScript code to the document. MigraDoc does not generate JavaScript code automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add "/select,"' text to the file path but it did not work: " /select, I:/path". I also thought it was imposibile.